# Alternatives to metadata buddy classes in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, data-annotations

I am trying to seperate DataAnnotations from our POCOs within a Silverlight project.  One way to do this outside of SL is to use buddy classes e.g:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(MyPOCO.POCOMetaData))]
public partial class MyPOCO
 {
     internal sealed class POCOMetaData
     {
         [Required(ErrorMessage="Requires name.")]
         public string Name { get; set; }
         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requires age.")]
         public string Age { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

However as of Silverlight 4, the MetadataType attribute does not exist within System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace.  Has anyone found an alternative way to seperate DataAnnotation attributes from POCOs?  I am looking into this as I was planning on using T4 templates to generate our basic POCO classes.

Comment: Are you sure? We've got exactly the same code in our SL 4 app which works just fine.

Comment: 100% sure.  Not sure how your app is working.  See (http://jeffhandley.com/) and read the "Is Silverlight's DataAnnotations a Subset of .NET's?" section.  There is also an interesting artice here: http://new.efficientcoder.net/2010/06/using-dataannotations-on-generated.html (I don't like the solution offered here that involves modifying code in the SL toolkit).

Comment: If I right click over `MetadataTypeAttribute` and go to definition I get a generated class from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` v4.0.30319. We're using RIA Services so I think @Shimmy's answer is relevant.

Comment: OK we are not using RIA Services...just plain WCF.  We are using version 2.0.5.0 of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario looks somehow strange, why wouldn't you want to decorate your POCOs themselves?

1 - If there is a matching server, consider using [WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/) and declare your POCOs at the server side, the RIA engine will then generate for you all the proxies at the client side, including all its annotations, and many other goodies.
2 - If there is no matching server and you want to manipulate the data on client side, then I would go for WPF and have a wider range of desktop development capabilities.
3 - Unfortunately, [`TypeDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx) is also not implemented in Silverlight, so you can't even add the attributes dynamically at runtime (in case you would want go that dirty-handed).

So I'm affraid your chances are:

1. Attach the MD to partial classes
2. Decorate your POCOs
3. Use WCF-RIA and declare the POCOs at the server-side
4. Go WPF
5. Please take a look on [PEM](http://pemdataannotation.codeplex.com). the EDMX designer can be extended, maybe the class designer can be extended too (oops, unfortunately seems it [isn't](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsclassdesigner/thread/746626e1-6532-4818-82b2-5a3f154c248e)).
6. [Suggest](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions) to the SL team for this feature to be implemented.

Comment: We want to code gen our POCOs and hence need to keep the dataannotations in a seperate class where they can be customised.  I guess we will have to drop the idea as there is no way we will consider using RIA Services at this stage.

Comment: @Myles, who's generating the POCOs?

Comment: We were planning on using T4 templates to generate the POCOs from a class diagram (in a similar fashion to Entity Framework).  I think we will scrap this idea due to the complexities discussed on this thread.  Our projects here are implemented using SL4, straight WCF and *NHibernate (*not my choice).

Comment: @Myles, I've added some content to my answer. I don't think I've added breaking news, but some info is also useful. HTH.